# How does brightness affect color?

Tags: visible-light, thermal-radiation, atmospheric-science, sun

How does brightness affect the color of light? For instance, the sun might be yellow because of the blue scattering when the light travels through the atmosphere - but if you look at it, it seems brighter and looks more white. So how does brightness affect the number of photons we perceive? Something must have an effect on the color because otherwise I cannot see why it would look white when not all photons are present.

Comment: Plus CIE space.

Comment: It does not answer my question. I am more concerned about why than what :(

Comment: The why is in cie color space and somehow in the As to the similar Q.

Comment: It is already in the way you posed it. The point is in the overlap between our spectral response and the solar spectrum. Details on this become biology ecc. Brightness can saturate our light receptor so that it might be tricky to discern the colour changes. Moreover think at the numerous illusions existing. On the other hand I still suggest to look at the other thread for the strictly physics part.